# 2 Stage Rust Docker Image, Failure to Compile chromiumoxide_cdp

Tags: docker, rust, chromium

I've been trying to get a 2 step docker image setup and I've been encountering many issues. The newest one I'm not sure how to fix involves my headless chromium library, and is the following:

```
#16 798.3 error: could not compile `chromiumoxide_cdp`
#16 798.3
#16 798.3 Caused by:
#16 798.3   process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name chromiumoxide_cdp --edition=2021 /usr/local/cargo/git/checkouts/chromiumoxide-b0a6fd9b32d92502/1eb7732/chromiumoxide_cdp/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=4618abc3b634c579 -C extra-filename=-4618abc3b634c579 --out-dir /usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl -L dependency=/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps -L dependency=/usr/src/app/target/release/deps --extern chromiumoxide_pdl=/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libchromiumoxide_pdl-3f92e4f213ea525d.rmeta --extern chromiumoxide_types=/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libchromiumoxide_types-99e1b123e0ccb7f5.rmeta --extern serde=/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde-ddfc800b9403f606.rmeta --extern serde_json=/usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde_json-dc59c7191ae94ed7.rmeta --cap-lints allow` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
------
process "/bin/sh -c cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release" did not complete successfully: exit code: 101
```

Here are my cargo dependencies:

```
tokio = { version = "1.12.0", features = ["full"] }
axum = { version = "0.6.18", features = ["ws"] }
anyhow = "1.0.71"
paris = { version = "1.5.15", features = ["no_logger", "macros"] }
once_cell = "1.17.1"
reqwest = { version = "0.11.17" }
serde = { version = "1.0.163", features = ["derive"]}
scraper = "0.16.0"
serde_json = "1.0.96"
chromiumoxide = { git = "https://github.com/mattsse/chromiumoxide", features = ["tokio-runtime", "_fetcher-rusttls-tokio"], default-features = false, branch = "main"}
base64 = "0.21.0"

futures = "0.3.28" # needed for chrome oxide tokio handler thread
openssl = { version = "0.10.52", features = ["vendored"] }
```

Here's my docker file:

```
################
##### Builder
FROM rust:slim as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src

# Create blank project
RUN USER=root cargo new app

# We want dependencies cached, so copy those first.
COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock /usr/src/app/

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt update && apt install -y perl make musl-tools

## Install target platform (Cross-Compilation) --> Needed for Alpine
RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

# This is a dummy build to get the dependencies cached.
RUN cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release

# Now copy in the rest of the sources
COPY src /usr/src/app/src/

## Touch main.rs to prevent cached release build
RUN touch /usr/src/app/src/main.rs

# This is the actual application build.
RUN cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release

################
##### Runtime
FROM alpine:latest AS runtime

# Copy application binary from builder image
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/app /usr/local/bin

EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/app"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why would it get hit with SIGKILL?

Comment: This could be OOMKiller, so it'd be worth monitoring memory usage during building closely.

Comment: @tadman Great point, tried building with -m 1g to allow a gig of memory and it took 16 minutes (longer than before) and crashed with the same error. I'll try again with 2 gigs haha. I think you are absolutely right, but I think something else is going wrong in chrome oxide generating whatever pdl files it needs.

Comment: If you're building Chrome or a browser engine, get ready to commit a *ton* of memory and time to building.

Comment: Yeah, even 2 gigs wasn't enough which is all my vps has. Not completely sure how to continue. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: You may need to provision a larger instance for this build, and shut it down after. Here's a [rough list of requirements](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md) which recommends 16GB as a baseline, with 8GB as an absolute minimum.

Comment: I'm gonna bang my head against the wall until I figure out how to compile for linux from my mac with the same issues. Thanks for all the help!!